# Sequel makes duplicate entries

Tags: ruby, sinatra, sequel

I'm using Sequel with Sinatra and I've been trying it out and I noticed that it creates duplicate entries (3x).I've tried to debug it but in the end I couldn't understand why is this occurring.

This is my code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'mysql2'
require 'sequel'

 DB=Sequel.connect(
                      :adapter => "mysql2",
                      :host =>"localhost",
                      :user => "root",
                      :password => "",
                      :database => "test"
                      )
  if !DB.table_exists? :users 
    DB.create_table :users do
      primary_key :id
      String :username ,:size=>20 #,:unique=>true
      String :password ,:size=>30 
  end   
  puts "Schema created"
else
  puts "Already exists"
end

  class User < Sequel::Model;end





class Test < Sinatra::Base

  get '/:username' do   
    "Creating user"
    User.create(:username => "#{params['username']}",:password => "test")
  end
end
```

Comment: You've commented out the unique constraint. The code above should create a new entry every time you visit the route.

Comment: @iain well yeah,but it creates 3 records instead .First I got Unique constraint violation I thought something is wrong so I checked without it and realized that each time you visit that route you create 3 new entries.

Comment: What happens if you load Sequel and your model into IRB and you run the `User.create…` method, do you get 3 entries then? How are you checking that you got 3 entries?

Comment: @iain solved it,problem was that I got error `ERROR Rack::Lint::LintError: Body yielded non-string value`.I added string response at the end and everything was fine.

Comment: Ah, very obvious now you've said it :) Glad you got it sorted.